# Entity Framework Core: may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am developing a REST API in .net core 3.1

I hava a Entity Shopping Cart Item:

```
        public class ShoppingCartItem
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Column("ticket_id")]
        public int? TicketId { get; set; }
        [Column("shopping_cart_id")]
        public int ShoppingCartId { get; set; }
        [Column("created_at")]
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        [Column("updated_at")]
        public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(TicketId))]
        public Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(ShoppingCartId))]
        public ShoppingCart ShoppingCart { get; set; }

        public ShoppingCartItem() { }

    }
}
```

I am using EF core as ORM, so I created my migrations, but when I try to update the DataBase the next error appears

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_ShoppingCartItem_Tikcet_ticket_id' on table 'ShoppingCartItem' may
>   cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or
>   ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints. Could
>   not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

By researching I have added the next lines to the DataContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    modelBuilder.Entity<ShoppingCartItem>().HasOne<Ticket>(t => t.Ticket).WithMany().HasForeignKey(s => s.TicketId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
}
```

But the error persist, I am not pretty sure if this is correct (I am a noob in this FrameWork). Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

This is my Ticket Entity:

```
public class Ticket
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("folio")]
    public string Folio { get; set; }
    [Column("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [Column("is_winner")]
    public bool IsWinner { get; set; }
    [Column("custom_name")]
    public string CustomName { get; set; }
    [Column("contestant_id")]
    public int ContestantId { get; set; }
    [Column("contest_id")]
    public int ContestId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(ContestantId))]
    public Contestant Contestant { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(ContestId))]
    public Contest Contest { get; set; }
    [Column("created_at")]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    [Column("updated_at")]
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    public Ticket() { }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your changes didn't applied on your migration.
You got the point of exception, but you need to remove last migration With Remove-Migration then add your migration again to apply you changes in

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ShoppingCartItem>().HasOne<Ticket>(t => t.Ticket).WithMany().HasForeignKey(s => s.TicketId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```